# Having DDC/CI detection issues with different USB-C adapters on Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, display-settings

I'm experiencing a challenging issue with DDC/CI communication between my laptop running Ubuntu Linux and two external monitors connected via a USB-C to HDMI adapter (hub).

While DDC/CI functions perfectly when using a direct HDMI connection, it fails to work through my USB-C to HDMI adapter.

Interestingly, a friend's identical adapter model (Anker 555) successfully enables DDC/CI communication on their setup, which makes me wonder whether or not the adapter works is down to luck.

Setup Details:

- **Laptop OS**: Ubuntu Linux, kernel 6.5.0-17-generic
- **CPU**: Intel i5-12500H
- **GPU driver**: i915
- **USB-C Hub 1**: [Anker 555](https://www.anker.com/products/a8383) USB-C Hub (8-in-1). I have one of these myself, which doesn't work with DDC. My friend has an identical one which does work (can change brightness etc).
- **USB-C Hub 2**: [Anker 332](https://www.anker.com/products/a8356) USB-C Hub. This one does not work with DDC.
- **External Monitor**: 2x Dell SE2422HX, connected via:

  - Direct HDMI (works with DDC/CI)
  - USB-C hubs outlined above

Troubleshooting Done:

1. Confirmed both monitors support DDC/CI (Have been able to use `ddcutil`, change brightness etc…).
2. `ddcutil` detects the monitors correctly but reports "DDC communication failed" for the setup with the "bad" adapter.
3. No firmware updates available for any of the adapters.
4. Here is the `ddcutil detect -verbose` output to compare when the two adapters are connected. Display 1 would be the one connected to the "working" adapter and the invalid display is the one that doesn't. In this case both adapters are the Anker 555:

```sh
Display 1
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-13
      DRM connector:                      card0-DP-1
      Driver:                             i915
      I2C address 0x50 (EDID) responsive: true 
      Is eDP device:                      false
      Is LVDS device:                     false
      /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-13/name    AUX USBC1/DDI TC1/PHY TC1
      PCI device path:                    /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/i2c-13
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               DEL - Dell Inc.
      Model:                DELL SE2422HX
      Product code:         41418  (0xa1ca)
      Serial number:        53D5WB3
      Binary serial number: 808863825 (0x30364851)
      Manufacture year:     2021,  Week: 16
      EDID version:         1.3
      Extra descriptor:        
      Video input definition:    0x80 - Digital Input
      Supported features:
         DPMS standby
         DPMS suspend
         DPMS active-off
         Digital display type: RGB 4:4:4 + YCrCb 4:4:4
         Standard sRGB color space: False
      White x,y:        0.313, 0.329
      Red   x,y:        0.650, 0.333
      Green x,y:        0.317, 0.615
      Blue  x,y:        0.151, 0.060
      Extension blocks: 1
   EDID source: I2C
   EDID hex dump:
              +0          +4          +8          +c            0   4   8   c   
      +0000   00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 ac ca a1 51 48 36 30   ............QH60
      +0010   10 1f 01 03 80 35 1e 78 ee 96 d5 a6 55 51 9d 26   .....5.x....UQ.&
      +0020   0f 50 54 a5 4b 00 71 4f 81 80 a9 c0 d1 c0 01 01   .PT.K.qO........
      +0030   01 01 01 01 01 01 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c   .......:..q8-@X,
      +0040   45 00 0f 28 21 00 00 1e 00 00 00 ff 00 35 33 44   E..(!........53D
      +0050   35 57 42 33 0a 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 44   5WB3.     .....D
      +0060   45 4c 4c 20 53 45 32 34 32 32 48 58 00 00 00 fd   ELL SE2422HX....
      +0070   00 30 4b 1f 54 12 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 01 0e   .0K.T...      ..
   VCP version:         2.1
   Controller mfg:      Mstar
   Firmware version:    41.2
   Monitor returns DDC Null Response for unsupported features: false

Invalid display
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-15
      DRM connector:                      card0-DP-3
      Driver:                             i915
      I2C address 0x50 (EDID) responsive: true 
      Is eDP device:                      false
      Is LVDS device:                     false
      /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-15/name    AUX USBC3/DDI TC3/PHY TC3
      PCI device path:                    /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-3/i2c-15
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               DEL - Dell Inc.
      Model:                DELL SE2422HX
      Product code:         41418  (0xa1ca)
      Serial number:        GHC5WB3
      Binary serial number: 808928849 (0x30374651)
      Manufacture year:     2021,  Week: 16
      EDID version:         1.3
      Extra descriptor:        
      Video input definition:    0x80 - Digital Input
      Supported features:
         DPMS standby
         DPMS suspend
         DPMS active-off
         Digital display type: RGB 4:4:4 + YCrCb 4:4:4
         Standard sRGB color space: False
      White x,y:        0.313, 0.329
      Red   x,y:        0.650, 0.333
      Green x,y:        0.317, 0.615
      Blue  x,y:        0.151, 0.060
      Extension blocks: 1
   EDID source: I2C
   EDID hex dump:
              +0          +4          +8          +c            0   4   8   c   
      +0000   00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 ac ca a1 51 46 37 30   ............QF70
      +0010   10 1f 01 03 80 35 1e 78 ee 96 d5 a6 55 51 9d 26   .....5.x....UQ.&
      +0020   0f 50 54 a5 4b 00 71 4f 81 80 a9 c0 d1 c0 01 01   .PT.K.qO........
      +0030   01 01 01 01 01 01 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c   .......:..q8-@X,
      +0040   45 00 0f 28 21 00 00 1e 00 00 00 ff 00 47 48 43   E..(!........GHC
      +0050   35 57 42 33 0a 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 44   5WB3.     .....D
      +0060   45 4c 4c 20 53 45 32 34 32 32 48 58 00 00 00 fd   ELL SE2422HX....
      +0070   00 30 4b 1f 54 12 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 01 e9   .0K.T...      ..
   DDC communication failed
```

Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered similar variability in DDC/CI functionality between identical adapter models?
2. Are there known workarounds or tools to enable DDC/CI communication over a USB-C to HDMI connection on Linux?
3. Could this issue be related to firmware differences within the adapters, and if so, is there a safe way to clone firmware from a working adapter to another?

Comment: “Has anyone encountered similar variability in DDC/CI functionality between identical adapter models?” It could be that there was a silent revision to the Anker 555 that Anker did not advertise.